# Does $H/N$ isomorphic to $K/N$ imply $H$ conjugates with $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Where $N$ is a normal subgroup of group $G$, and $H$, $K$ are subgroups of $G$ containing $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**:

Take $Q_8$ with $H=\langle i\rangle$, $K=\langle j\rangle$ and $N=\langle-1\rangle$.

**or**

Take $D_8=\langle r,j\mid r^4=j^2=1,jr=r^{-1}j\rangle$, with $H=\langle r\rangle$,  $K=\langle r^2,j\rangle$ and $N=\langle r^2\rangle$.

**or**

Take $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ with $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\{0\}$, $K=\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $N=\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\{0\}$.

Comment: And it can of course fail much worse, since the subgroups need not even be isomorphic.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Of course, you are right! I added an example.

Comment: And $G$ is additionally abelian (again of order $8$).